# Network Connection Icon not shown

Tags: vpn

I am unable to install purevpn on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 because I cannot find the Network Connection Icon. I have fumbled around with no positive results. My goal is to install Purevpn. I need a very clear set of instructions as I am not really good at this. Please help. Thank you.

The closest thing to the network connection icon is a bar graph icon that lists the wifi and ethernet

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is shown as:

- [image: nm-applet on mate-panel disconnected Wi-Fi] (for disconnected wireless connection);
- [image: nm-applet on mate-panel connected Wi-Fi] (for active wireless connection);
- [image: nm-appley on mate-panep - connected Ethernet] (for active Ethernet connection);

Try to reset appearance of `mate-panel` with `mate-tweak` (installable with `sudo apt-get install mate-tweak`):

1. Go to **Interface** section
2. In **Panels** under **Select a panel layout to change the user interface** select **Ubuntu MATE**
3. If you have checked **Enable indicators** in **Panel Features** you can toggle it.

If it does not show you may try to kill and relaunch it with:

```
killall nm-applet
nm-applet &
```

This icon has drop-down menu. You can click on this icon and select **Edit Connections...** option, it should open **Network Connections** window.

If can't find this icon you could try to open **Network Connections** window with
`nm-connection-editor` command from terminal (accessed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>). And try to add VPN connection here.

For VPN support usually you need to install OpenVPN with:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
sudo service network-manager restart
```

You can follow PureVPN guides:

- [Setup your Linux system through MATE Desktop Environment](https://support.purevpn.com/setup-your-linux-system-through-mate-desktop-environment)
- [OpenVPN Configuration Guide for Linux/Ubuntu Version 16](https://support.purevpn.com/openvpn-configuration-guide-for-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could the bar-graph icon be the network connection icon? The icon shows bars relative to strength i think. But the real quest is to get Purevpn installed.

Comment: I think I need  update the problem. The icon I see on my screen must serve the same purpose as the icon you show.   The instructions from Purevpn say: Do the following:

Click on “Network Connection Icon…“
Go to VPN Connections and select “Configure VPN…“  It is grayed out. I think icon I see serves the same purpose as your. Now I need to figure out how to get access to the grayed out "configure VPN"

Comment: I updated my answer. I assumed, that you using modern OpenVPN.